# How to listen to Notification in Javascritpt in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push-notification

I have an html file, When this page is open, in a certain condition, there will be a desktop notification. I want to listen to notification happens, and run some scripts.

```
<html>
...
<script>

    var title = document.title

    if (notification happens) {
       window.onblur = function() {
         document.title = "You got a new msg";

       };

    }
    window.onfocus = function() {
        document.title = title;
     };
</script>
...
</html>
```

I there any way to find out `if (notification happens)`?

Comment: `a desktop notification` - can you explain this

Comment: I think you are the one triggering the notification, then you can call the desired func right ?

Answer (score 0):

You cna listen for `.onclick` like a proper DOM element, or add an event listener:

```
notification.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //you can only access the event (e) in this case
});
```

or as a click

```
notification.onclick = e => {
    //you can only access the event (e) in this case
}
```